# SPUtility.ParseDate - format of the input date string

Tags: date-time, sputility

In the `SPUtility.ParseDate` function, the 2nd parameter is the date in string format. Is there any specific format required for this? Will it work with any format? The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms477635.aspx) for this API is not at all useful.

Can anyone please explain with examples?

Comment: Can you provide more info of what are you trying to do?